# ScaleM() method changes the shader effects in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, shader, matrix-multiplication

I increased the size of the object using the ScaleM(modelMatrix, offset, x, y, z) method:

```
...
protected val projectionMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelViewMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val mvpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
...
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0)

Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f)
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f)
Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, 15f, 15f, 15f) // enlarge object
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0)
...
```

The object increased but this affected its display (Illumination increased and iridescence decreased in my case). Is there an easy way to avoid this, or do I need to reconfigure the shader and input parameters for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better option, but I found the following solution:

```
private val modelViewMatrixForShader = FloatArray(16)
...
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f)
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f)
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrixForShader, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0) 
Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, 15f, 15f, 15f) 
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0)
... 
fun getMVMatrixAsFloatBuffer(): FloatBuffer = floatBuffer(modelViewMatrixForShader)
...
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixLink, 1, false,
        view.getMVMatrixAsFloatBuffer());
```